# How to get Customs data for importing companies?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, data-request, statistics, free-trade

I am looking for customs data for importing companies for each country.
I found some of them, for instance [Canadian Importers Database](https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/557ccb8d-d035-420d-bfd7-47dfbe0cd18b)

But I wonder if any of you know the additional free sources. Especially in case of China or USA.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

How to access such data is often described in published papers using data on imports. For the US, see for instance:
Flaaen, Aaron, Ali Hortaçsu, and Felix Tintelnot. 2020. "The Production Relocation and Price Effects of US Trade Policy: The Case of Washing Machines." American Economic Review, 110 (7), 2103-27.

See also their online appendix at:
https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20190611